# Replacing DependencyProperty by AttachedProperty in class hierarchy - is that possible?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties, attached-properties

I want some of my `Button`, `ToggleButton` and `RadioButton` to have a Geometry property so that I can use in ControlTemplates to avoid boilerplate when assigning instance-specific Geometries to those controls.

For example, currently I can write this:

```
<my:GeometryButton Geometry="{StaticResource OneGeometry}"/>
<my:GeometryButton Geometry="{StaticResource OtherGeometry}"/>

<!-- ...and inside the Style for GeometryButton: -->
<ContentControl TargetType="{x:Type my:GeometryButton}">
    <Border>
        <Path Data={TemplateBinding Geometry}/>
    </Border>
</ContentControl>
```

With this GeometryButton class:

```
public class GeometryButton : Button
{
    static GeometryButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(GeometryButton),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(GeometryButton)));
    }


    public Geometry Geometry
    {
        get { return (Geometry)GetValue(GeometryProperty); }
        set { SetValue(GeometryProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty GeometryProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Geometry",
                                    typeof(Geometry), 
                                    typeof(GeometryButton), 
                                    new PropertyMetadata(default(Geometry)));

}
```

The problem is, if I am to define `GeometryToggleButton` and `GeometryRadioButton` classes, I am supposed to repeat the DependencyProperty code in each class, violating DRY.
Also, since RadioButton derives from ToggleButton, and the later and Button in turn derive from ButtonBase, I think I could take advantage of this, but if I need to inherit from each class separately, I don't benefit from inheritance at all.

So I considered to use AttachedProperties, but the tutorials and examples usually mention examples like `DockPanel.Dock`, `Grid.Left`, or `Control.Foreground`, implying the existence of some "Parent", so I am not sure of:

- Does the AttachedProperties concept applies to my use case in the first place?
- If yes, how am I supposed to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a regular attached property. In your control templates, use it.

No seriously, there's not a lot more to it than that.

For example, I wrote an attached `CornerRadius` property so that many different control styles could specify a `CornerRadius`, which would be used by their templates.

```
public static class Attached
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CornerRadiusProperty
            = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "CornerRadius",
                typeof(CornerRadius), 
                typeof(Attached),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                    new CornerRadius(0), 
                    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender 
                        | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, 
                    PropertyChanged)
                );

    public static CornerRadius GetCornerRadius(DependencyObject uie)
    {
        return (CornerRadius)uie.GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty);
    }

    public static void SetCornerRadius(DependencyObject uie, CornerRadius value)
    {
        uie.SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value);
    }
}
```

XAML

**N.B.** The parens around `(edcorpext:Attached.CornerRadius)` in the `Binding` are critical, so it understands that the string is one indivisible path segment referring to an attached property; otherwise it tries to parse it as a path to a property of `Binding.Source`, hits the `:`, and throws an exception.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="EdCorpButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Grid>
        <Border 
            x:Name="PART_BackgroundBorder"
            CornerRadius="{Binding (edcorpext:Attached.CornerRadius), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
            BorderThickness="1.3"
            BorderBrush="{StaticResource ControlBorderBrush}"
            Background="{StaticResource EdCorpGrayMediumGradientBrush}"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
            />
        <!-- etc. etc. etc. -->

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
    <Setter Property="edcorpext:Attached.CornerRadius" Value="{StaticResource ButtonCornerRadius}" />
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource EdCorpButtonTemplate}" />

    <!-- etc. etc. etc. -->
```

They told me we needed the UI on this application to look "more modern" and since we don't have a real designer who knows what he's doing, I put asymmetrical rounded corners on stuff. It was actually a lot worse before.

Comment: Interesting! Do you think it would be possible, with the implementation you provided, to declare the CornerRadius directly in the button instance? For example `<Button CornerRadius="{StaticResource SmallRadius}"/><Button CornerRadius="{StaticResource LargeRadius}"/>` ?

Comment: @heltonbiker `<Button edcorpext:Attached.CornerRadius="{StaticResource LargeRadius}"/>`. Just like any dependency property. That's the beauty of it! The same mechanism is used. The template gets the value (that is, it gets it if it asks for it, of course).

Comment: Ok, gonna try it and post some feedback! Thanks!

Comment: @heltonbiker Cool. Just be wary of what you give to `Binding.Path`; it needs the parentheses to understand that `ns:ClassName.PropName` is one identifier indicating an attached property.